# Regex pattern for a function call

Tags: java, regex

I have defined following pattern to parse our own custom for a function which is: `<functionName>[<arg1>, <arg2>, ..]` and the pattern is:
`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\[(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(,([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*?)*?\\]`

Now when I run this against an example function: `properCase[ARG1,ARG2]`, I get the following output:

```
Total matches are: 5
Group number 0is: properCase[ARG1, ARG2]
Group number 1is: properCase
Group number 2is: ARG1
Group number 3is: ARG1
Group number 4is: ,ARG2
```

Code:

```
        Matcher m = funcPattern.matcher("properCase[ARG1, ARG2]");
        System.out.println("Match found: " + m.matches());
        System.out.println("Total matches are: " + m.groupCount());
        if (m.matches())
        {
            for (int index= 0 ; index < m.groupCount(); index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Group number "+ index + "is: " +m.group(index));
            }
        }
```

How can I only extract out the function name (as group 1) and argument  list (as group 2, group 3)? I am not able to eliminate the `,` from the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to use the regex you provided to match `properCase[ARG1, ARG2]`, but to answer your question more generally, you should use non capturing groups `(?:your_regex)` to not include it in the matcher groups

**EDIT:**

If you aren't married to using a single regex to do the parsing, consider the following: split up the string into function name and arguments groups, and then split the arguments group by the delimiter ,

```
import java.util.regex.*
String regex="([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\[([ ,.a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\]"
Pattern funcPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = funcPattern.matcher("properCase[ARG1, ARG2, class.otherArg]");
        System.out.println("Match found: " + m.matches());
        System.out.println("Total matches are: " + m.groupCount());
        if (m.matches())
        {
            for (int index= 0 ; index <= m.groupCount(); index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Group number "+ index + "is: " +m.group(index));
            }
        }
println "Arguments: " + m.group(2).split(",");
```

Produces:

```
Match found: true
Total matches are: 2
Group number 0is: properCase[ARG1, ARG2, class.otherArg]
Group number 1is: properCase
Group number 2is: ARG1, ARG2, class.otherArg
Arguments: [ARG1,  ARG2,  class.otherArg]
```

Comment: thank you! You won't be able to capture if the input string has spaces between the arguments. `ARG1,ARG2` should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the comma in its own group to work around it.

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\[(([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(,)(([a-zA-Z0-9])+)*?)*?\\]`